Predicting Values with Bayesian Neural Network
I want to use a Bayesian Neural Network for a regression task.
To do that I converted a BNN from this paper to Python 3. The provided training script runs and I receive a pickle file, which I want to use to predict a value for my regression. Event though the loss for the training doesn't really go down, but this seems also be the case for the models used in the paper.
The input of my network is a vector with 59 features, where one feature is my target variable. It's pretty similar to the boston housing dataset.
The MLP inside the BNN returns two vales: $\mu$ and $\sigma$.
If I understand BNNs correctly $\mu$ and $\sigma$ refer to the mean and standard deviation of my input and I should use $\mu$ to predict my values.
But when I use input vector I always receive a value that is roughly around the mean of my target variable.
So lets say the mean is 62. When I insert a vector from my test set, that should return the target variable 142, I will get 61. When I do the same with a vector, that should return 21, I will get 63. So my predicted values are always around the mean of the target variable.
What do I have to do, to get real predictions from my input data?
I never worked with BNNs before and it's quite hard to find any resources on how I should model my network. Maybe someone has a nice tutorial to learn how I can use this model to predict my target variable. I have to use this class and can't use Pyro or any other framework currently, because otherwise I can't use the other components from the paper.
To predict the values I used the predict() method from the converted BNN Class:
class GaussianBNN(BaseNet):
    def __init__(self, model, N_train, lr=1e-2, cuda=True, eps=1e-3, grad_std_mul=20):
        super(GaussianBNN, self).__init__()
        self.lr = lr
        self.model = model
        self.cuda = cuda

        self.N_train = N_train
        self._create_network()
        self._create_optimizer()
        self.schedule = None  # [] #[50,200,400,600]
        self.epoch = 0

        self.grad_buff = []
        self.grad_std_mul = grad_std_mul
        self.max_grad = 1e20
        self.eps = eps

        self.weight_set_samples = []

    def _create_network(self):
        torch.manual_seed(42)
        if self.cuda:
            torch.cuda.manual_seed(42)

        if self.cuda:
            self.model.cuda()
            cudnn.benchmark = True

        print('Total params: %.2fM' % (self.get_nb_parameters() / 1000000.0))

    def _create_optimizer(self):
        self.optimizer = StochasticHamiltonMonteCarloSampler(params=self.model.parameters(), lr=self.lr, base_C=0.05, gauss_sig=0.1)

    def fit(self, x, y, burn_in=False, resample_momentum=False, resample_prior=False):
        self.set_mode_train(train=True)
        x, y = variable_to_tensor_list(variables=(x, y), cuda=self.cuda)

        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        mu, sigma = self.model(x)
        sigma = sigma.clamp(min=self.eps)
        loss = -diagonal_gauss_loglike(y, mu, sigma).mean(dim=0) * self.N_train

        loss.backward()

        if len(self.grad_buff) > 100:
            self.max_grad = np.mean(self.grad_buff) + self.grad_std_mul * np.std(self.grad_buff)
            self.grad_buff.pop(0)

        self.grad_buff.append(nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(parameters=self.model.parameters(),
                                                       max_norm=self.max_grad, norm_type=2))
        if self.grad_buff[-1] >= self.max_grad:
            print(self.max_grad, self.grad_buff[-1])
            self.grad_buff.pop()

        self.optimizer.step(burn_in=burn_in, resample_momentum=resample_momentum, resample_prior=resample_prior)

        return loss * x.shape[0] / self.N_train, mu, sigma

    def eval(self, x, y):
        self.set_mode_train(train=False)
        x, y = variable_to_tensor_list(variables=(x, y), cuda=self.cuda)
        mu, sigma = self.model(x)
        sigma = sigma.clamp(min=self.eps)
        loss = -diagonal_gauss_loglike(y, mu, sigma).mean(dim=0) * self.N_train

        return loss * x.shape[0] / self.N_train, mu, sigma

    @staticmethod
    def unnormalised_eval(pred_mu, pred_std, y, y_mu, y_std, gmm=False):
        ll = gaussian_mixture_model_loglike(pred_mu, pred_std, y, y_mu, y_std, gmm=gmm)  # this already computes sum
        if gmm:
            pred_mu = pred_mu.mean(dim=0)
        rms = get_root_mean_square(pred_mu, y, y_mu, y_std)  # this already computes sum
        return rms, ll

    def predict(self, x):
        self.set_mode_train(train=False)
        x, = variable_to_tensor_list(variables=(x,), cuda=self.cuda)
        mu, sigma = self.model(x)
        return mu, sigma

    def save_sampled_net(self, max_samples):

        if len(self.weight_set_samples) >= max_samples:
            self.weight_set_samples.pop(0)

        self.weight_set_samples.append(copy.deepcopy(self.model.state_dict()))

        logger.warning(f"Saving Samples: {len(self.weight_set_samples)} for Max Samples: {max_samples}")
        logger.warning(f"Samples: {self.weight_set_samples}")

        return None

    def sample_predict(self, x, num_samples, grad=False):
        self.set_mode_train(train=False)
        if num_samples == 0:
            num_samples = len(self.weight_set_samples)

        x, = variable_to_tensor_list(variables=(x,), cuda=self.cuda)

        if grad:
            self.optimizer.zero_grad()
            if not x.requires_grad:
                x.requires_grad = True

        mu_vec = x.new(num_samples, x.shape[0], self.model.output_dim)
        std_vec = x.new(num_samples, x.shape[0], self.model.output_dim)

        # iterate over all saved weight configuration samples
        # TODO: mu_vec and std_vec are changed here, prove that the value isnt changed inplace
        for idx, weight_dict in enumerate(self.weight_set_samples):
            if idx == num_samples:
                break
            self.model.load_state_dict(weight_dict)
            mu, std = self.model(x)

            mu_vec[idx] = mu.detach().clone()
            std_vec[idx] = std.detach().clone()

        if grad:
            # TODO: check if same things are returner here
            return mu_vec[:idx], std_vec[:idx]
        else:
            return mu_vec[:idx], std_vec[:idx]

    def get_weight_samples(self, num_samples=0):
        weight_vec = []

        if num_samples == 0 or num_samples > len(self.weight_set_samples):
            num_samples = len(self.weight_set_samples)

        for idx, state_dict in enumerate(self.weight_set_samples):
            if idx == num_samples:
                break

            for key in state_dict.keys():
                if 'weight' in key:
                    weight_mtx = state_dict[key].cpu()
                    for weight in weight_mtx.view(-1):
                        weight_vec.append(weight)

        return np.array(weight_vec)

    def save_weights(self, filename):
        save_object(self.weight_set_samples, filename)

    def load_weights(self, filename):
        self.weight_set_samples = load_object(filename)

The referenced model here is the following MLP:
class GaussianMLP(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, width, depth, output_dim, flatten_image):
        super(GaussianMLP, self).__init__()

        self.input_dim = input_dim
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        self.width = width
        self.depth = depth
        self.flatten_image = flatten_image

        layers = [nn.Linear(input_dim, width), nn.ReLU()]
        for i in range(depth - 1):
            layers.append(nn.Linear(width, width))
            layers.append(nn.ReLU())
        layers.append(nn.Linear(width, 2 * output_dim))

        self.block = nn.Sequential(*layers)

    def forward(self, x):
        if self.flatten_image:
            x = x.view(-1, self.input_dim)
        x = self.block(x)
        mu = x[:, :self.output_dim]
        sigma = F.softplus(x[:, self.output_dim:])

        return mu, sigma

You can find the training script here: [LINK]

First, let me suggest to first fully understand the tool, and only then use it, otherwise you will probably miss the whole point of it
Anyway, the $\mu, \sigma$ parameters you are referring are the Gaussian approximation you are choosing for $p(y|x,\theta)$. If you are only interested in the mean $\mu$, I'm not too sure that you need all of that parametrization that you are doing
The fact that you are using a BNN it's not too clear from your explanation.
However, you observation about "is predicting always the mean", it's a clear sign of the data you are using, more than the model you are using. Indeed, if $x$ carries zero information about the variable $y$, then the model will indeed predict always the mean.

The paper that I'm implementing produces counterfactual explanations through this BNN. The generation of CLUEs (Counterfactual Latent Uncertainty Explanations) is working and I can generate all graphics related to the quantization of uncertainty inside the model. Now I want to use the BNN model to predict things for me. The paper did several regression tasks like LSAT,Wine Regression. I'm trying to train this on my own medical dataset, but I struggle to get meaningful predictions. Mainly I'm not sure how to predict the $y$ values for my $x$ input. The pre-trained models also suffer from this

so I think that my approach on how to predict values is not correct. Basically I first load the model, insert my normalized $x$ inside the GaussianBNN and call the predict method. This gives me the $\mu$ and $\sigma$ mentioned, where I would assume, that the $\mu$ is the predicted $y$ for the given $x$ value. In fact it's always nearly the same value around the mean of my target variable.
I agree, that I should first understand the "tool", but to be honest with you I can't really find literature, that matches my problem or can't link the literature to my problem. Maybe you have smth for me

@LukasScholz yes $\mu$ is the expected y|x, but it’s a distribution, so it’s pausible that you are not getting exactly the target if the data has not enough predictive power
